# Convert DatetimeIndexResampler to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to build a matrix from series but before that I have to resample those series. However, to avoid processing the whole matrix twice with `replace(np.nan, 0.0)` I want to append the dataframes to a collecting dataframe and then remove `NaN` values in one pass.

So instead of

```
user_activities = user.groupby(["DOC_ACC_DT", "DOC_ACTV_CD"]).agg("sum")["SUM_DOC_CNT"].unstack().resample("1D").replace(np.nan, 0)
df = df.append(user_activities[activity].rename(user_id))
```

I want

```
user_activities = user.groupby(["DOC_ACC_DT", "DOC_ACTV_CD"]).agg("sum")["SUM_DOC_CNT"].unstack().resample("1D")
df = df.append(user_activities[activity].rename(user_id))
```

but that is not working because `user_activities` is not a dataframe after `resample()`.

The error suggests that I try `apply()` but that method expects a parameter:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _make_wrapper(self, name)
    507                    "using the 'apply' method".format(kind, name,
    508                                                      type(self).__name__))
--> 509             raise AttributeError(msg)
    510 
    511         # need to setup the selection

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'rename' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is `user_activities` after `resample`?

Comment: resample no longer returns a dataframe: it's now "lazyly evaluated" at the moment of the aggregation or interpolation.

=> depending on your use case, replacing `.resample("1D")` with `.resample("1D").mean()` (i.e. downscaling) or with `.resample("1D").interpolate()` (upscaling)  could be what you're after, and they both return a dataframe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The interface to `.resample` has changed in Pandas 0.18.0 to be more groupby-like and hence more flexible ie `resample` no longer returns a DataFrame: it's now "lazyly evaluated" at the moment of the aggregation or interpolation.

I suggest reading resample API changes http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#resample-api

See also:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

## for upscaling

```
df.resample("1D").interpolate()
```

## for downscaling

### using mean

```
df.resample("1D").mean()
```

### using OHLC

ie open high low close values or first maximal minimal last values

```
df.resample("1D").ohlc()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html).

As per the docs, note first that `.agg` is an alias for it, and is preferred:

> agg is an alias for aggregate. Use the alias.

It can be used as in the example below:

```
df.resample('1D').agg({'close': 'last', 'open': 'first'})
```

This returns a dataframe.