# AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'rolling'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributes, rolling-computation

i have a problem i running this code

```
resamp = pd.DataFrame()
station_ids = list(set(weather_data.station_id.tolist()))
for _id in station_ids:
idx = weather_data.station_id == _id
ti = time_index[idx]

wdfi = weather_data[idx].set_index(ti)
floating = wdfi[['visibility','temperature','wind_speed', "wind_dir", "Rain"]]
binaries = wdfi[['visibility','temperature','wind_speed', "wind_dir", "Rain"]]
b = binaries.resample('1h').rolling(24).apply(lambda x: x.any())
f = floating.resample('1h').agg({
    'wind_speed': 'mean',
    'visibility': 'mean',
    'temperature': 'mean',
    'wind_dir':'mean',
    'Rain':'mean'
})

temp = pd.concat((f,b),axis=1)
temp['station_id'] = _id
resamp = resamp.append(temp)
```

and I get this **error**

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      8     floating = wdfi[['visibility','temperature','wind_speed', "wind_dir", "Rain"]]
      9     binaries = wdfi[['visibility','temperature','wind_speed', "wind_dir", "Rain"]]
---> 10     b = binaries.resample('1h').rolling(24).apply(lambda x: x.any())
     11     f = floating.resample('1h').agg({
     12         'wind_speed': 'mean',

~\Anaconda3\envs\arcpro\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in **getattr**(self, attr)
     95             return self[attr]
     96 
---> 97         return object.**getattribute**(self, attr)
     98 
     99     @property

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'rolling'

my pandes v 24
thank you

Answer (score 1):

answer by SvenD could be what you're looking for :
[How to convert DatetimeIndexResampler to DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492004/how-to-convert-datetimeindexresampler-to-dataframe)

> "resample no longer returns a dataframe: it's now "lazily evaluated"
> at the moment of the aggregation or interpolation. => depending on
> your use case, replacing `.resample("1D")` with
> `.resample("1D").mean()` (i.e. downscaling) or with
> `.resample("1D").interpolate()` (upscaling) could be what you're
> after, and they both return a dataframe.

– Svend Sep 15 '16 at 8:57"